# AmazonS3Client doesn't return keys on terminating prefixes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting an odd behavior while using the AmazonS3Client from the AWS SDK in java.  Let's say for example I have a bucket (org.magic.bucket) that has the following contents:

```
data/2016/03/10/
data/2016/03/11/
data/2016/03/12/
data/2016/03/13/
data/2016/03/14/
data/2016/03/15/
data/2016/03/16/
```

Each one has a collection of files in it for example:

```
A.txt
B.txt
C.txt
```

And I have a java code snippet that looks like:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects("org.magic.bucket", "data/2016/03/1")

while (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
      System.out.println(objectSummary.getKey());
    }
    objectListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
 }
```

That returns this:

```
 data/2016/03/10/A.txt
 data/2016/03/10/B.txt
 data/2016/03/10/C.txt
 data/2016/03/11/A.txt
 data/2016/03/11/B.txt
 data/2016/03/11/C.txt
 data/2016/03/12/A.txt
 etc ...
```

Which I expect, but when I call the same code with "data/2016/03/11" as the prefix I get no data returned.  This is problematic because I need to process only the files in a "folder".  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set (or the code you're using sets) the delimiter (in the request sent to the S3 API) to `/` then the result you see is correct -- because there are no objects with the prefix `data/2016/03/11` *occurring before the next delimiter*.

Asking for `data/2016/03/11` tells S3 you are looking for something more like `data/2016/03/11A.txt` -- no more slashes in the name.

If you set the prefix to `data/2016/03/11/` (adding the trailing slash) then you should get the results you expect.

Comment: I have tried with the prefix set to data/2016/03/11/ and it also isn't returning anything.  Should I be using     ListObjectsRequest instead and explicitly setting the delimiter?  I haven't had much success with that approach either.

Comment: `while (objectListing.isTruncated()) {` ... wouldn't that do nothing with the "last" group of objects?  Which would also be the first group, if there are fewer than 1000 objects...

Comment: Ah yes your right, I switched to a do while and now it works.  Bad design on my part, Thanks.

Comment: A [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) sometimes comes in handy for problems like that one. :)